# Can I write a word as background in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart, cryptocurrency, forex, candlesticks

I googled how to write a word in Pinescript, but i found nothing..!!

1 - the word should be at the center of the screen

2 - font size = 32 , border orange

[Example 1 click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoxsI.png)

[Example 2 click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j54ju.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can plot text using the functions `plochar` or `label.new`.

Comment: Thanks :) , but how to use it to make aword as background and center at the middle of the page ?

Comment: You can't position elements relative to the chart's space in Pine.